# Status bar is not hidden in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, statusbar, xcode5

I add this value to plist: "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to "NO".  - DONT WORK this method

And this don't work too
@property(nonatomic, getter=isStatusBarHidden) BOOL statusBarHidden

Please help
I will be grateful for the detailed description of what and where to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to `NO` in your plist, and then add this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

(You can use whatever UIStatusBarAnimation value you want.)

Alternatively, you can leave "View controller-based status bar appearance" on, and in your view controllers, add this method:

```
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

When you want to change whether the status bar is hidden/shown based on the value of the above method, your view controller can call the `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` method.